# Online source for Kanji etymology

Tags: kanji

Is there a good website that contains etymological explanations about the 2000 most important Kanji?

I'm looking for something like this:
http://tokyogreenspace.com/2009/08/05/weed-in-kanji-the-language-of-nature/
Could be shorter of course.

Comment: I just typed "kanji etymology" into Google, and clicked the first result. It seems to be what you want, except maybe that you have to type the kanji yourself, which doesn't seem to be a big deal to me. (It also seems to be more correct than that website you linked to, which simply breaks the characters up into radicals and invents a story around them.)

Comment: hey, you mean http://www.kanjinetworks.com? it seems the search option does not work as anonymous user. After I logged in everythink works. Yes, it basically does what I was looking for. Do you want to add an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it? The search works for me!

Comment: In response to a similar question, a user posted their meta-search of several etymology websites: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2675/1478

Comment: On Meta there is a [question about resources](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/756/37) with a rather good section filled with [dictionaries](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/761/37).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kanjinetworks.com/eng/kanji-dictionary/online-kanji-etymology-dictionary.cfm

Comment: If you recommend this website then perhaps you could add it to the resources page on the meta site?

Comment: Note: this link now goes to a site talking about the morning after pill

Comment: this site no longer exists